# Why won't JS redirect the webpage when statement is true?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, window.location

I have an input for username and one for password.  When the username and/or password don't match, I successfully get the "alert", but when they do match, nothing happens.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have tried `windows.location.replace` as well, with the same results.

```js
function user1() {
    var user = document.getElementById('username').value
    var pass = document.getElementById('password').value
  
    if (user == "admin" && pass == "password1") {
        window.location ("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
    else {
        alert('incorrect username or password')
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="username" id="user">User</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username">
    <br>
    <label for="password">Pass</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    <br>
    <button onclick="user1()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure `if (user == "admin" && pass == "password1")` is a secure approach?

Comment: I'm giving him the benefit of the doubt and guessing that this is just practice/learning code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
```

instead of a function call. The other problem was the button causing a page reload. To fix that you should do:

```
<button type="button" onclick="user1()">Submit</button>
```

`type="button"` will prevent it from submitting the form by default.

---

**demo**

```js
function user1() {
  var user = document.getElementById('username').value
  var pass = document.getElementById('password').value
  
  if (user == "admin" && pass == "password1") {
   window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  }
  else {
    alert('incorrect username or password');
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="username" id="user">User</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username">
  <br>
  <label for="password">Pass</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="user1()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `<button type="button" ...` just to expand on this: the default value for `type` is `sumbit`, so the form was getting submitted

Answer (score 2):

`window.location="url"`

```js
function user1() {
  var user = document.getElementById('username').value
  var pass = document.getElementById('password').value
  
  if (user == "admin" && pass == "password1") {
   window.location="http://stackoverflow.com";
}

  else {
    alert('incorrect username or password')
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="username" id="user">User</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username">
    <br>
    <label for="password">Pass</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    <br>
    <button onclick="user1()">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for `window.open`, where `window.location` will also work

```js
function user1() {
  var user = document.getElementById('username').value
  var pass = document.getElementById('password').value

  if (user == "admin" && pass == "password1") {
    window.open("https://stackoverflow.com");
  } else {
    alert('incorrect username or password')
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="username" id="user">User</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username">
  <br>
  <label for="password">Pass</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <br>
  <button onclick="user1()">Submit</button>
</form>
```